# My java code is flawed, but i dont understand why

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am very new at java and my be missing something very basic.  When i run my code i am trying to add value to accounts created in the code.  When i try to run the code i recieve an error that a file cannot be found, but i thought that the file was created inside the code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

class DoPayroll
{
public static void main(String args[])
                                    throws
        IOException     
{
    Scanner diskScanner =
        new Scanner(new File("EmployeeInfo.txt"));

    for (int empNum = 1; empNum <= 3; empNum++)
    {
        payOneEmployee(diskScanner);
    }
}

static void payOneEmployee(Scanner aScanner)
{
    Employee anEmployee = new Employee();

    anEmployee.setName(aScanner.nextLine());
    anEmployee.setJobTitle(aScanner.nextLine());
    anEmployee.cutCheck(aScanner.nextDouble());
    aScanner.nextLine();
}
}
```

once run i recieve the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: EmployeeInfo.txt (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:636)
at DoPayroll.main(jobexe.java:11)
```

i thought that in the above code using `new Scanner(new File("EmployeeInfo.txt")` would create the new file once i input a value.  Please give me a simple solution and an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mistaking instantiating an instance of class File with actually writing a temp file to Disk. Take this line

```
Scanner diskScanner =
        new Scanner(new File("EmployeeInfo.txt"));
```

And replace it with this

```
File newFile = File.createTempFile("EmployeeInfo", ".txt");
Scanner diskScanner = new Scanner(newFile);
```

Edit: Peter makes a good point. I'm face palming right now.

Comment: -1: What is the point of creating an empty temporary file and reading it?  You know it won't have anything in it.

Answer (score 2):

It will create a new file when you write to it.  However to read from it, it must already exist.  You might like to check it exists with

```
File file = new File("EmployeeInfo.txt");
if (file.exists()) {
    Scanner diskScanner = new Scanner(file);
    for (int empNum = 1; empNum <= 3; empNum++)
        payOneEmployee(diskScanner);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `File` object can't find the filename you've passed. You either need to pass the full path of `EmployeeInfo.txt` to `new File(...)` or make sure current working directory is the directory that contains this file.

Answer (score 1):

The `File` constructor does not create a file.  Rather, it creates the information in Java needed to access a file on disk.  You'd have to actually do file IO in Java using the created `File` for a new file to be created.

The [Scanner constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.io.File%29) requires an existing `File`.  So you need a full path to the real, valid location of `EmployeeInfo.txt` or to create that file using File I/O first.  [This tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) on I/O in Java will help.

Answer (score 0):

You thought wrong :D A `Scanner` needs a existing file, which seems quite logical as it reads values and without a existing file its difficult to read. The [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.io.File%29) also states that:

> Throws:
>       FileNotFoundException - if source is not found

**So, in short: You must provide a readable, existing file to a scanner.**

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer explain, the file is not created just by using `new File("EmployeeInfo.txt")`.
You can check is the file exists using

```
File file = new File("EmployeeInfo.txt");
if(file.exists()) {
  //it exists
}
```

or you can create the file (if it doesn't exists yet) using

```
file.createNewFile();
```

that method returns `true` if the file was created and `false` if it already existed.